# Cloned "Sort Results" but values are missing

Tags: sxa

In Sitecore 9.1 and SXA 1.8, I cloned `SortResults` rendering and used it in variant like this

[image], it's configuration is [image] and it's data source is[image] but the sort results like as there are three options for sorting but their values not appear [image],
Is there something I missed ?? Any Ideas ??

Comment: And if you don't use Component Renderer but add your cloned search results component as regular component to the page. Does it work? As I have seen before not all components can be used in Component Renderer

Comment: Please check what Peter has suggested. If it won't work you can ping me directly on the slack next week (I'm off for a whole week now) and I can try to reproduce it as this might be a bug.

Comment: Thanks Peter and Dawid, I found the reason of this issue when I recompiled Sitecore.XA.Feature.Search dll I found that Templates.SortingGroups.Fields.Title refer to SXA sorting group not cloned one so when I cloned again from Sort Results rendering I choosed option of "Inherit from existing datasource" not "Make a copy of original datasource", it works.